# python: copy only missing files from FTP dirs and sub-dirs to local dirs and sub-dirs

Tags: python, list, compare, directory, ftplib

the *problem* is:

I have a local directory **'/local'** and a remote FTP directory **'/remote'** full of subdirectories and files.  I want to check if there are any new files in the sub-directories of **'/remote'**.  If there are any, then copy them over to **'/local'**.

the *question* is:

am I using the right strategy?  Is this totally overkill and is there a much faster pythonic way to do it?
DISCLAIMER:  I'm a python n00b trying to learn.  So be gentle ... =) 
This is what I've tried:

Create a list of all files in /local and its sub-dirs.

```
LocalFiles=[]
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(localdir): 
    for name in files:                     
        LocalFiles.append(name)
```

Do some ftplib magic, using [ftpwalk()](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/499334-remove-ftp-directory-walk-equivalent/) and copying its results to a list of the form:

```
 RemoteFiles=[['/remote/dir1/','/remote/dir1/','/remote/dir3/'],['file1.txt','file12.py','file3.zip']]
```

so I have the directory corresponding to each file.
Then see which files are missing by comparing the lists of filenames,

```
missing_files= list(set(RemoteFiles[1]) - set(LocalFiles))
```

and once I've found their name, I try to find the directory that came with that name,

```
for i in range(0,len(missing_files)):
    theindex=RemoteFiles[1].index(missing_files[i])
```

which lets me build the list of missing files and their directories,

```
MissingDirNFiles.append([remotefiles[0][theindex],remotefiles[1][theindex]])
```

so I can copy them over with **ftp.retrbinary**.
Is this a reasonable strategy?  Any tips, comments and advice is appreciated [especially for large numbers of files].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the modification time of both the local and the remote FTP directories and store it in a data base, you could prune the search for new or modified files. This should speed up the sync procedure significantly.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  I forgot to mention that the sub folders in /local and /remote are different.  New files in /remote need to be sent to their "pigeonholes" in /local according to some criteria (some regex related to the name, but not the dir).

Comment: Ok, I see, but still you could speed up the localization of new or modified files in /remote by looking for changes in the modification time of sub directories in /remote.